# How to copy paste error messages from JetBrains Rider?

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider

I have the following Popup from JetBrains Rider:

[image]

How can I focus an error message in JetBrains Rider so I can copy paste that message and Google why Rider thinks I should not start my source code with a comment.

**UPDATE 1:**

The file extension is .cs

**UPDATE 2:**

The source compiles fine and I haven't found any other place where the message appears. It's seems to be one of those warnings which are configured by default to appear as error message.

Comment: what is the file extension?

Comment: That's just a tooltip, surely Rider has an _Output window_ when it compiles?

Comment: File extension is .cs and compiles just fine. It's seems to be one of those warnings which are configured by default to appear as error message,

Answer (score 0):

I restarted JetBrains Rider only to be greeted by an “Application damaged” error message. So deleted and reinstalled JetBrains Rider and now I get a proper inspection popup:

[image]

And with this now more helpful warning I was able to correct the problem.

**Answer:** You installation is broken, reinstall JetBrains Rider.